# How to animate a ball becoming smaller in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a ball become increasingly smaller using HTML5 canvas. I've been able to make it grow larger, so I figured the reverse would be simple. What am I doing wrong here? Console.log shows me values from 11 to 0 decreasing by 1. When x is less than 0, it stops. But the ball doesn't change shape, and I suspect its because it's drawing smaller shapes on top of each other, perhaps? I thought clearRect would work for that?

```
function draw2()
{
    console.log(x);
    context2D.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context2D.arc(10, 10, x, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context2D.fill();
    x -= 1;
    if (x < 0) {
        clearInterval(s);   
    }
}
```

A demo is available at: http://www.chronicled.org/dev/test.html

Thanks!

Comment: Draw a white circle of radius x, decrement x, then draw the black circle. This is more of a work-around than a fix, but it might give you some insight into what's going wrong.

Comment: it's worth nothing (maybe!) that your example will not work in IE9. You need to include `<!DOCTYPE html>` to trip standards mode (I know this is just a test page, but according to the spec it's not an optional element in HTML5). Also, IE9 doesn't support the `const` keyword so it chokes on `const FPS = 30` and won't evaluate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `context2D.beginPath();` to the beginning of draw2  (it also wouldn't hurt to have it in draw)

the .fill is filling the whole path which includes the old arcs

Answer (score 3):

The `fill()` call is filling the old rect again.  Try this instead:

```
function draw2()
{
    console.log(x);     
    context2D.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

     context2D.beginPath();
     context2D.arc(15, 15, x, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
     context2D.fill();
     context2D.closePath();
    x -= 1;
    if (x < 0) {
        clearInterval(s);   
    }
}
```